# Adding elements to a generics list

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I have the following method:

```
private void updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<Order> orders) {  
   // processing code here       
   List<Order> updates = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Data d: data) {
      Order anOrder = createOrder(d);
      if(anOrder != null) {
         updates.add(anOrder);
      }  
   }  
   orders.clear();  
   orders.addAll(updates);   
}
```

The method `createOrder` will create a subtype of `Order` based on the `Data` argument. This part compiles.

But the problem is that the calling code of the method will not compile since it is called as follows:

```
updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<PendingOrder> orders)
```

and

```
updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<ExecutedOrder> orders)
```

both of these are subtypes of `Order` and hence the code won't compile on the *calling* side of the method.

If I update the code as follows:

```
private void updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<? extends Order> orders) {  
       // processing code here       
       List<Order> updates = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Data d: data) {
          Order anOrder = createOrder(d);
          if(anOrder != null) {
             updates.add(anOrder);
          }  
       }  
       orders.clear();  
       orders.addAll(updates);   // <= does not compile
    }
```

The problem is with the line: `orders.addAll(updates);`
That does not compile of course because the list is declared as `List<? extends T>` and it tries to avoid adding items of different types in the list.

So how can I use generics so I reuse the function and be able to update the list in the method?

Comment: @matt: which one is the "original list"? The calling code? In the calling code the existing code is using such references and I can't change that area of the code. I want to just reuse the method for both list types

Comment: "The calling code?" yes, the code you don't include, but would be very helpful for somebody to find you a solution. What you're describing isn't really possible because you have a `List<Execute>` or a `List<PendingOrder>` and you want to add an `Order` to it.

Comment: @matt: the calling code is: `updateEntries(data, listOfPendingOrders)` and `updateEntries(data, listOfExecutedOrders)`. Both are subtypes of `Order`

Comment: You don't actually show the creation of these lists. Or the class they're using. You should make a complete example. The answers provided should compile but since you cannot get it to compile, there are some details missing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `updateEntries` gives you back a `List<Order>`. You can't add the elements of a `List<Order>` to a `List<? extends Order>` because the latter - as in your example - may not expect to have any subclass of `Order` added to it.

For example, if `updateEntries` returns a `List` where some/all of the entries are `CompletedOrder`s, you shouldn't muddle those up with `PendingOrder`s. So the compiler won't allow you to do that.

You need to be able to pass in another "thing" which allows you to ensure that the things returned by `updateEntries` will be instances of the element type required by your `orders` list.

For example:

```
private <T extends Order> void updateEntries(List<Data> data, Function<Order, T> orderFn, List<T> orders) {  
   // processing code here
   
   // Pass in orderFn here too:
   List<T> updates = updateEntries(data, orderFn);  

   orders.clear();  
   orders.addAll(updates); // <- does not compile   
}
```

Alternatively, if `orderFn` is literally just something you can apply to each of your elements in this method, you can do something like:

```
private <T extends Order> void updateEntries(List<Data> data, Function<Order, T> orderFn, List<T> orders) {  
   // processing code here

   orders.clear();
   updateEntries(data).stream().map(orderFn).forEach(orders::add);
}
```

At the call site, you need to pass in the extra function, e.g.

```
updateEntries(listOfData, PendingOrder.class::cast, listOfPendingOrders);
```

which passes in a `Function` that just casts the `Order`s to `PendingOrder`s.

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the original problem. The calling method won't compile. I am calling it with lists of different subtypes

Comment: At the call site, you need to pass in the extra function, e.g. `updateEntries(listOfData, PendingOrder.class::cast, listOfPendingOrders)`.

Comment: What is `PendingOrder.class::cast`?

Comment: It's a method reference which casts things to `PendingOrder`, so you can use it as a `Function<Order, PendingOrder>`.

Comment: I can not use the second example you provided. So focusing on your first snippet, it still will not compile because the original problem is there in the calling side

Comment: I don't know the details and limitations of your code. You're going to need to provide more information if you want a solution; but this explains what the problem is and *an* approach to solving it.

Comment: I updated the code because I tried to simplify it originally but turns out I messed up, I am sorry about that. The structure is now in the post. My confusion is how can I add the list list, regardless of what subtype the order is. The `createOrder` returns the proper subtype based on data

Comment: The problem/solution hasn't really changed given your edit: `createOrder` returns an `Order` (whether or not it returns a subtype isn't visible to the compiler: the return type is `Order`, so it could be any subtype of `Order`), you can't add that to a `List<? extends Order>`; you need to pass in a "thing" so you can create an instance of `T` from your data, e.g. a `Function<Data, T>`.

Comment: Is the solution to move that loop to another function as in your code example then?

Comment: You are using `List<T>` in the method argument. But my calling code will need to call `List<Subtype>` and that does not compile

Comment: "and that does not compile" did you declare a bounded type variable, as shown in the answer, and use it as both the element type of the list and the return type of the function?

Comment: I suspect I confused you and you have focused on the wrong thing. Let me fix the post again

Comment: I updated the post. I hope this is better now. Apologies again

Comment: Nothing in the edits really changes the answer. `Order anOrder = createOrder(d);` is the problem: you need those `Order`s to be something compatible with the `orders` list. Casting it to `T` (as in `T anOrder = (T) createOrder(d);`) isn't safe because it's an unchecked cast: doing that prevents the compiler checking correctness, so you're likely to end up with heap pollution. You have to pass in something which guarantees you instances of `T` (or null), either from the `Data` in the list, or from the `Order` returned by `createOrder`. (cont)

Comment: That means injecting either a `Function<Data, T>` or a `Function<Order, T>` (or a `Function<? super Data, ? extends T>` or a `Function<? super Order, ? extends T>`, if you want it to be more flexible).

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that the the type parameter of the order list is in a covariant position in `updateEntries` and in a contravariant position for the `addAll` call, making it effectively invariant. Unless this is reflected in the type the code does not compile. Suggestions to adjust the type accordingly have been given in this answer and along similar lines in my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the difference between `<? extends T>` and `<? super T>`.

There is a good answer here: [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

If i'am right your code should look like this (but i did not test it):

```
private <T extends Order> void updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<T> orders) {  
   // processing code here       
   List<T> updates = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Data d: data) {
      T anOrder = (T)createOrder(d);
      if(anOrder != null) {
         updates.add(anOrder);
      }  
   }  
   orders.clear();  
   orders.addAll(updates);   
}
```

Comment: No, that still does not compile in the calling side

Comment: Do you have still the compiler error on "orders.addAll(updates); "?

Comment: I have changed my code a little bit. So it should fit your needs.

Comment: The calling code `updateEntries(data, pendingOrderList)` does not compile

Comment: @Jim Does it say why it isn't compiling? Benjamin, why both with the <T extends Order> and not just use a <T> ?

Comment: @Jim here is a small example of it compiling and working. If this doesn't work for you it is because you are omitting some details. https://ideone.com/pNSIXx

Comment: @matt: But in your snippet you dont add anything inside the function

Comment: @Jim I am just trying to demonstrate the calling code. You're saying the part `updateEntries(data, pendingOrderList)` doesn't compile. What is the error you're getting from the compiler?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not type-safe: `(T) createOrder(d)` is an unchecked cast to `T`. If `createOrder` returns something that's not a `T` (say, a `CompletedOrder` rather than a `PendingOrder`, if `orders` is a `List<PendingOrders>`), you won't find out until after `updateEntries` has completed.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the `createOrder` function that creates a subtype of `Order` without being explicit about it. Change that signature to

```
<T extends Order> T createOrder(Data data)
```

and be explicit about the type `T` in the `updateEntries` method:

```
<T extends Order> void updateEntries(List<Data> data, List<T> orders)
```

If you cannot change the signature of `createOrder` for any reason, wrap the call into a private method and add a cast there.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not type-safe: `createOrder` would have to do an unchecked cast to `T`. This is described more here: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/TypeParameterUnusedInFormals

Comment: @AndyTurner, agree. The origin of the problem however is, that there is no type that satisfies the OP's original question. See also my comment re. variance in the other answer. With this in mind, something has to give. Either by casting, like Benjamin Schüller proposes in his answer, or by emulating a sort of family type polymorphism like my answer does or doing the same via a extra function like you propose in your answer.